# why the input size is varies in pretrained models using keras?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

the pretrained models such as vgg16, inception v3, mobilenet, resnet152 and so.
please give some knowledge about this.
why this input size differ from one model to another?

vgg16 299*299
resnet 224*224
inception v3 299*299 
mobilenet 224*224

Answer (score 1):

All of these models are implementations of particular scientific papers, which all used different input sizes. Some models use the published weights, meaning that if you want to use these weights to reproduce their results, then you have to use the same input size.

But note that this applies only if you use the pretrained weights from the ImageNet dataset, if you want to train these models from scratch (random initialization), then you can specify a different `input_shape` without any issue, just respecting some constraints due to the depth of the model.